# How to return values from foreach loop in tcl

Tags: foreach, tcl

I have a list of all the files in the directory.  I have stored them in a variable `file_list`. I want to get the tail name for each file. My approach is like this.

```
set file_list [list /a/b/a.txt /a/b/b.txt /a/b/c/file1.tcl /a/b/c/file2.tcl]

proc file_tail {filename} {
   set x {}
   set f_tail [file tail $filename]
   lappend x $f_tail
return $x

}

foreach ft $file_list {
    set f_tail [file_tail $ft]
}
```

but `f_tail` only contains last value stored i.e. "file2.tcl" Please guide me. I want a list of all tail values of file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are making a list of all the tails, do this:

```
set f_tail {}
foreach ft $file_list {
    lappend f_tail [file tail $ft]
}
```

If your helper function is going to do the `lappend`, you need to keep the variable holding the list outside the procedure:

```
proc file_tail {filename listVariable} {
    upvar 1 $listVariable theList
    set f_tail [file tail $filename]
    lappend theList $f_tail
}

set tails {}
foreach ft $file_list {
    file_tail $ft tails ;  # <<< NAME, so not $tails as that would READ the variable
}
```

Note that we are passing in the *name* of the variable (`tails` outside) and using `upvar 1` inside the procedure to make a linked local variable (`theList` inside) that can be updated. However, you can't do it by passing in a list *value*; Tcl uses copy-on-write semantics for its values. You need to be careful about the difference between the names of variables and the values they contain; they're not the same.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest either:

```
set f_tail {}
foreach ft $file_list {
    lappend f_tail [file_tail $ft]
}
```

or (if you have a later version of Tcl):

```
set f_tail [lmap ft $file_list {file_tail $ft}]
```

Documentation:
[foreach](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/foreach.htm),
[lappend](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/lappend.htm),
[lmap (for Tcl 8.5)](http://wiki.tcl.tk/40570),
[lmap](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/lmap.htm)